# Implement Java hasNext() and next() in C++

Tags: c++, interview-questions, iterator

Recently came upon this question asked in interview with major tech company.

> Implement Java's next and hasNext function in your favorite
>   programming language.

Here is the solution I came up with. I am not sure whether `next()` is implemented correctly. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is the `iterator` documentation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class iterator {
public:
    iterator() {}
    iterator(std::vector<T> vec) {
        container = vec;
    }
    bool hasNext() {
        if (curr_pos == container.size()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (curr_pos < container.size()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    T next(){
        if (hasNext()) {
            curr_pos += 1;
            return container.at(curr_pos-1);    
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> container;
    int curr_pos = 0;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> int_vec {1,2,3,4};
    iterator<int> int_it(int_vec);
    while (int_it.hasNext()) {
        std::cout << int_it.next() << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::string> str_vec {"a", "b", "c","d"};
    iterator<std::string> str_it(str_vec);
    while(str_it.hasNext()) {
        std::cout << str_it.next() << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> empty_vec;
    iterator<int> empty_it(empty_vec);
    while(empty_it.hasNext()) {
        std::cout << empty_it.next() << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/8w6qhj) is the working version of the above code.

Answer (score 8):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Make sure all control paths return

Within your implementation of `next()`, what happens if `hasNext()` is not true?  The calling function will be expecting a type `T` but it won't get anything.  This should be addressed.

### Consider throwing an error

The Java version of `next()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if there are no more elements.  You could reproduce this behavior by actually deleting code (which would also address the above issue):

```
T next(){
    return container.at(curr_pos++);    
}
```

This works because `at` throws a `std::out_of_range` error if there are no further items.

### Think carefully about signed vs. unsigned

The `curr_pos` member does not have a reasonable interpretation for negative values, so it would make more sense to declare it `unsigned` rather than `int`.

### Prefer modern initializers for constructors

The constructor could be written using the more modern parameter intialization style.  That version would look like this:

```
iterator(std::vector<T> vec) 
    : container{vec}, curr_pos{0} 
{}
```

### Use const where practical

The current `hasNext()` routine does not (and should not) modify the underlying object, and so it should be declared `const`:

```
bool hasNext() const { /* code */ }
```

### Simplify expressions

The `hasNext()` routine is overly complex.  It could instead be this single line:

```
bool hasNext() const {
    return curr_pos < container.size();
}
```

### Use `const` references where practical

The constructor could and should take a `const` reference to avoid a copy and to preserve flexibility.  You could also use default parameters to eliminate the no-argument constructor:

```
iterator(const std::vector<T> &vec = {}) 
    : container{vec}, curr_pos{0} 
{}
```

### Consider providing an initializer list constructor

The code has a few versions of something like this:

```
std::vector<int> int_vec {1,2,3,4};
iterator<int> int_it(int_vec);
```

It would be convenient to instead be able to write this:

```
iterator<int> int_it{1,2,3,4};
```

Here is a constructor that will allow that usage:

```
iterator(const std::initializer_list<T>& v) 
    : container{v}, curr_pos{0} 
{}
```

Answer (score 6):

**My code review issues**

- You implemented your iterator only for std::vector. From Java documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html see All Known Implementing Classes) I assume it must be also available for other containters.
  So the main problem is that your iterator only works with std::vector but I think it must work with other C++ containers too. As a result the type of the container must be the template parameter and your iterator must wotk with std::deque, std::list, std::map, std::unordered_map, std::set and so on.
- Your code actually does not impement fully `Interface Iterator<E>`. See methods for `Interface Iterator<E>`:

  ```
  boolean     hasNext();
  E           next()
  void        remove()
  ```

  You implemented only `hasNext()` and `next()`. Why not implement `remove()` even though it is optional?
- Then, you make a deep copy of std::vector. However from the quoted below phrase I assume that your iterator should instead store lvalue reference to the container and not copy it:

  > Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by
  >   this iterator
- `T next()` is likely has to be `T& next()` since there is no point in copying value and Java itself (in my opinion) does not copy element in next()
- You broke the specification here:

  ```
  T next()
  {
      if (hasNext()) {
          curr_pos += 1;
          return container.at(curr_pos-1);    
      }
  }
  ```

  What Java iterator promises:

  > ```
  > Throws:
  > NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no more elements
  > ```

  Your code in that case does not throw - this is a difference with the spec. You should have thrown an exception.

  ```
  T next()
  {
      if (hasNext()) {
          curr_pos += 1;
          return container.at(curr_pos-1);    
      }
      throw std::runtime_error("the iteration has no more elements");
  }
  ```
- You could have added make_iterator function to create iterators in this way:

  ```
  auto int_it = make_iterator(int_vec);
  ```

---

**google codestyle code review issues**

google codestyle analyzer (https://github.com/google/styleguide) found this issues in your code:

```
>python "styleguide\cpplint\cpplint.py" main.cpp
main.cpp:7:  public: should be indented +1 space inside class iterator  [whitespace/indent] [3]
main.cpp:9:  Single-parameter constructors should be marked explicit.  [runtime/explicit] [5]
main.cpp:22:  Missing space before {  [whitespace/braces] [5]
main.cpp:25:  Line ends in whitespace.  Consider deleting these extra spaces.  [whitespace/end_of_line] [4]
main.cpp:28:  private: should be indented +1 space inside class iterator  [whitespace/indent] [3]
main.cpp:28:  "private:" should be preceded by a blank line  [whitespace/blank_line] [3]
main.cpp:34:  Missing space after ,  [whitespace/comma] [3]
main.cpp:42:  Missing space after ,  [whitespace/comma] [3]
main.cpp:44:  Missing space before ( in while(  [whitespace/parens] [5]
main.cpp:50:  Missing space before ( in while(  [whitespace/parens] [5]
```

---

**My attempt**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class T>
class java_iterator {
 public:
    explicit java_iterator(T* container)
      : container(container), current(container->begin()) {
      }

    bool hasNext() {
        return current != container->end();
    }

    typename T::value_type& next()  {
        if (current != container->end())
            return *current++;
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("the iteration has no more elements");
    }

 private:
    T* container;
    typename T::iterator current;
};

template <class T>
java_iterator<T> make_java_iterator(T* container) {
    return java_iterator<T>(container);
}

int main() {
    {
        std::vector<int> int_vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
        java_iterator<decltype(int_vec)> int_it(&int_vec);
        while (int_it.hasNext()) {
            std::cout << int_it.next() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    try {
        std::vector<int> int_vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
        java_iterator<decltype(int_vec)> int_it(&int_vec);
        while (true) {
            std::cout << int_it.next() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> int_vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
        auto int_it = make_java_iterator(&int_vec);
        while (int_it.hasNext()) {
            std::cout << int_it.next()  << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::deque<int> int_vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
        java_iterator<decltype(int_vec)> int_it(&int_vec);
        while (int_it.hasNext()) {
            std::cout << int_it.next() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::list<int> int_vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
        java_iterator<decltype(int_vec)> int_it(&int_vec);
        while (int_it.hasNext()) {
            std::cout << int_it.next() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```